# I want the textbox AJAX Mask Edit Extender to change based on a radio button selection

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I creating an ASP.net online application with C# background.  I am also using AJAX MaskEditExtender.  I'm pretty new to AJAX and don't know Javascript. What I need to do is have the textbox AJAX mask change based on the selection of the radio buttons. 
In this example they are choosing salary or hourly. I need the salary to be "999,999" and the hourly to be "99.99".

```
<asp:TextBox ID="finalwage" runat="server" Width="80px">$</asp:TextBox>
<!-- Salary Mask -->
    <asp:MaskedEditExtender 
            ID="MaskedEditExtender1" 
            runat="server" 
            TargetControlID="finalwage" 
            Mask="999,999" 
            MessageValidatorTip="true" 
            MaskType="Number" 
            InputDirection="RightToLeft" 
            AcceptNegative="None" 
            ErrorTooltipEnabled="true">
    </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
    <asp:MaskedEditValidator 
            ID="MaskedEditValidator1" 
            runat="server" 
            ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender1" 
            IsValidEmpty="true" 
            MinimumValue="0" 
            MaximumValueMessage="Must enter a number" 
            ControlToValidate="finalwage" >
    </asp:MaskedEditValidator>
    <!-- Hourly Mask -->
    <asp:MaskedEditExtender 
            ID="MaskedEditExtender2" 
            runat="server" 
            TargetControlID="finalwage" 
            Mask="99.99" 
            MessageValidatorTip="true" 
            MaskType="Number" 
            InputDirection="RightToLeft" 
            AcceptNegative="None" 
            ErrorTooltipEnabled="true">
    </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
    <asp:MaskedEditValidator 
            ID="MaskedEditValidator2" 
            runat="server" 
            ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender1" 
            IsValidEmpty="true" 
            MinimumValue="0" 
            MaximumValueMessage="Must enter a number" 
            ControlToValidate="finalwage" >
    </asp:MaskedEditValidator>
```

.......

```
<asp:RadioButtonList 
        ID="RadioButtonList1" 
        runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="true" 
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Hourly" Value="Hourly"
    <asp:ListItem Text="Salary" Value="Salary" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Heres the C# code that I thought would work:

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "Hourly")
    {
        MaskedEditExtender1.Mask = "99.99";
    }
    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "Salary")
    {
        MaskedEditExtender1.Mask = "999,999";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking it's a typo, but you're forgetting a "SelectedValue" in the first if statement

Comment: yeah i just noticed that 2 seconds ago, presume i have it in there

Comment: Sounds good. So when the radio button selection is changed, does it post back, or is it sent through AJAX? It's been awhile since I've worked ASP.NET, but I guess my question should be "Are the radio buttons in an UpdatePanel?"

Comment: And sorry, but I think it's another typo - in your first if statement, do you mean to have `==`, not `=`? And not that if matters, but I would make them an if/else if/else

Comment: i've tried both...neither of them make a difference...and its been a while since i've coded asp.net as well...i'd like to postback but not sure how per click

Comment: Well, you definitely need `==` in the if statement part, then use `=` when setting `.Mask`. Using if/else if/else isn't too necessary for this, but I just wanted to point it out. Are you using an UpdatePanel at all? Or is this a normal page with postbacks? Like, does the page "reload" when you change the radio button?

Comment: No update panel (never used them before) Just a standard asp.net page as far as i remember in order for it to "postback" i have to click a submit button of sorts (correct?)

Comment: Good to know. No, you don't need it a click to post back...but that is an example. Setting certain events for the ASP controls sets up post backs automatically - it renders the HTML for it to happen. So when you specify `OnSelectedIndexChanged` for the radio button list, ASP.NET generates HTML that watches for the selected radio button to change...when it does, it posts back to the server and runs the function you specify - `RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged`. Do you see anything happen when you choose a different radio button? Does it look like the page submits?

Comment: Nope it just sticks with the hourly mask which is annoying because i thought my logic was right.  If the server sees that i have selected a different button it should change the mask.  This is why i'm scratching my head about this...doesn't make sense, i even tried two different textbox's and it didn't work...i also tried two different maskeditextenders as well and made one visible and one not when certain selections are present. My guess is that its not posting to the server.

Comment: I believe you that it isn't working, but I just wanted to verify that it is definitely getting to the server. If you could verify it's getting to the server, then we know that's not the problem. So all I wanted to know is if you can see the page is being reloaded because changing the radio button causes a postback. Is that happening?

Comment: i also tried two different maskeditextenders as well and made one visible and one not when certain selections are present. My guess is that its not posting to the server

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but do you have a form on your page?

Comment: no question is a dumb question...i'm editing a site from a previous employee and he used the stepwizard, so if that is a form then yes...there are however no <form...> tags, figured stepwizard was a form

Comment: Hmm let me check - I've never used it. I have a feeling it is not, and that's definitely a factor of why it's not hitting the server. Unless I'm wrong, you NEED a form on the page in order to utilize any form of postbacks or ASP controls submitting to the server. Of course, you can manually cause a postback in Javascript, but I know you're not attempting that here.

Comment: well i'm not opposed to it...i just dont know javascript what-so-ever so if i can get code for javascript and where to put it and whatnot i'm not opposed to that (my boss gave me open ended time) and i told him i may have to learn JS :) soooo i got time :)

Comment: I got it...joe was right i had to put it into the page load portion...i feel dumb

Comment: Sorry, all I meant is that if you don't want to use a form, it is still possible to cause postbacks with javascript (I wouldn't advise unless you wanted custom events to occur or using a form isn't possible). And I just meant that in your code, you clearly aren't using javascript, so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged code to Page_Init. I believe RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged is too late in the lifecycle process to change the mask.

Comment: I would agree, but I feel like that's no different than a button's click event. And in button click events, you can definitely change properties of controls. Or do you think it's different with MaskedEditExtender?

Comment: Yeah that's only on page load, if i pressed refresh and had selected index changed per reload it would make sense, but in this it wouldnt

Comment: Okay joe you were right:
    if(Page.IsPostBack)
{
         
        if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "Hourly")
        {
            MaskedEditExtender1.Mask = "99.99";

        }
        if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "Salary")
        {
            MaskedEditExtender1.Mask = "999,999";
        }

}

Comment: Awesome! My hunch was right. Plz mark as the 'best' answer. Thanks!